# Height of particular node in a binary tree

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree

```
int finddepth(Node *node,int key)
{
 if(node==NULL)
  return 0;
  if(node->data==key)
  return 1;
  return max(depth(node->left),depth(node->right));
}
```

I just want to calcuate height or depth of a particular node.How will I increment depth. I know this program always return 1.

Comment: width first algorithm. Until works...

Comment: Indent your code, please.

Comment: The `root` variable which you use in `if(root->left==node||root->right==node)`... where is it defined?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need help on Binary Tree height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608113/need-help-on-binary-tree-height)

Answer (score 0):

I think no need to make complex you can try following code

```
     int finddepth(Node* root)
     {
      if(root==NULL)
       return 0;
      int l=finddepth(root->left);
      int r=finddepth(root->right);
      if(l>r)
        return l+1;
      return r+1;
      }
```

Comment: A matter of taste, but at least `std::max` for returning is shorter: `return std::max(l,r) + 1;` (as already in the question)

Comment: Really only need `return node ? std::max(finddepth(node->left), finddepth(node->right)) + 1 : 0;`